# On self-duality of N=4 super Yang Mills theories

Tags: yang-mills, duality

I am looking at S-duality a bit, and was wondering if anyone had the answer to the following question.  It is known that the supersymmetric Yang-Mills theory in 4 space dimensions is self-dual with gauge group or U(N) or SU(2).  But is it known whether there are more Yang-Mills theories that are self-dual? On the other hand, is it known that some are not?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Generally, S-duality of SYM4 exchanges a theory with gauge group G with a theory of the Langlands dual of G, as described in [this](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/21466/on-self-duality-of-n-4-super-yang-mills-theories?show=21505#a21505) discussion.